# How to create entity IDs in the createSlice reducer prepare function

Tags: javascript, redux, immutability, redux-toolkit

I'm having some trouble with the `prepare` callback function included in my `addEntity` reducer I include in redux-toolkit's `createSlice` function.

I'm trying to use the `prepare` callback to add unique IDs to my action payloads.

The [redux-toolkit `createSlice` documentation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createslice) says:

> If you need to customize the creation of the payload value of an action creator by means of a prepare callback, the value of the appropriate field of the reducers argument object should be an object instead of a function. This object must contain two properties: reducer and prepare. The value of the reducer field should be the case reducer function while the value of the prepare field should be the prepare callback function.

Here is the code I am using (written w/ TypeScript):

```
import { createSlice, createEntityAdapter } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { MyEntityType } from '../../js/types/MyEntityType';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

const myEntityAdapter = createEntityAdapter<MyEntityType>();

const { reducer, actions } = createSlice({
    name: 'myEntity',
    initialState: myEntityAdapter.getInitialState(),
    reducers: {
        addEntity: {
            reducer: myEntityAdapter.addOne,
            prepare: (payload) => ({...payload, id: uuidv4()}),
        },
        removeEntity: myEntityAdapter.removeOne,
        updateEntity: myEntityAdapter.updateOne,
    }
});
```

When I compile my app and test creating an entity using the `addEntity` action, however, the `prepare` callback doesn't appear to do anything.

Here is the action I dispatch using Redux DevTools:

```
{
 type: 'myEntity/addEntity',
 payload: {myPayloadTrait: 100, id: 'test'} // Expected behavior: this id should be overwritten in the prepare callback
}
```

Resulting state:

```
myEntity: {
    ids: {
        0:"test"
    },
    entities: {
        "test": {
            myPayloadTrait: 100
            id: "test"
        }
    }
}
```

Why doesn't my prepare callback overwrite the `"test"` id before the payload is passed to the reducer? Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prepare callback *must* return an object that looks like `{payload?, meta?, error?}`.  Your code is currently returning the intended payload directly.

Change it to:

```js
addEntity: {
  reducer: myEntityAdapter.addOne,
  prepare: (payload) => ({
    payload: {
      ...payload,
      id: uuidv4()
    }
  }),
}
```